# Como puedo dar click a una imagen con un Zindex especifico

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

tengo un problema necesito detectar el evento click en un imagen con un index en especifico, antes de dar click se el id de la imagen a la que quiero dar click, pero me impide detectar el evento click en la imagen que quiero porque hay otras imagenes con z index mas alto, agradezco la ayuda para resolver este problema.

Answer (score 1):

A las imágenes que estén por encima le pides añadir un “pointer-events:none” en CSS para que no les afecte el evento de click